# How to check if a request for static file is passing through ASP.NET pipeline in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to know if there is any way I can check if the request for `static` files like `images/css` etc is handled from `asp.net` pipeline or not.

I have set `runAllManagedModules=false` in `web.config` and added ignore routes as well.
The load times have come down. Which indicates that the requests are probably not passing through the `asp.net` pipeline.

However, is there a way I can ascertain the same?

Browsers i Used: `IE/ Firefox`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If request goes through ASP.NET request pipeline, it should call all the registered http-modules.

1. Add custom http-module (if you don't have one).
2. Put breakpoint inside.
3. Run app in debug mode.
4. Initiate request of any static content.

If breakpoint is reached, request probably goes through ASP.NET pipeline. To make sure, you can check the url of the request in debug mode.